# Android PlayStore App/ Launcher icon

Tags: android

I am designing an App for Android PlayStore and have a launcher icon related question. I know there used to be a set rounded corner radius of 5% for all launcher icons, but I see many free form App/ Launcher icons on the PlayStore these days.  Does anyone know if this is a strict design regulation anymore? Or will Google still feature (Editors Choice) your App with a free form App launcher icon?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From [Android launcher icon design guidelines](https://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#launcher):

> **Style**
>
> Use a distinct silhouette. Three-dimensional, front view, with a
>   slight perspective as if viewed from above, so that users perceive
>   some depth.